# Не выводит результат во втором Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup, асинхронность

Я новичок. Использую Jsoup для парсинга страницы (пока что пытаюсь просто вытащить №группы) и AsyncTask для разделение потоков, парсить придется достаточно. У мен есть 2 Activity и к ним 2 класса. Один класс наследует от другого. Внутри одного класса есть еще один, который наследуется как раз таки от AsyncTask. Тут у меня сравнивается введенная пользователем группы с имеющимися данными в массиве, после выдает результат (ту же группу и выдает) во втором Activity (Это выдает нормально). А AsyncTask подключается к странице, ищет тег с классом и тоже передает текст во второй активити. Но не отображается, что не так?
Скидываю именно этот класс:

```
public class SearchGroup extends MainActivity implements TextWatcher {
    private AutoCompleteTextView group;
    protected String[] spisokGrp = {"ИВ-14-1", "ИВ-14-2", "ИВ-14-21", "ИВ-201", "ИВ-202",
            "ИВ-301", "ИВ-302", "ИВ-401", "ИВ-402", "ИП-14-22", "ИП-14-3", "ИП-14-4", "ИП-203",
            "ИП-204", "ИП-303", "ИП-304", "ИП-312", "ИП-403", "ИП-404", "ИП-411", "РА-14-5", "РА-14-6",
            "РА-205", "РА-305", "РА-314", "РА-405", "РА-414", "РЭ-14-7С", "СР-14-12", "СР-14-13",
            "СР-208", "СР-308", "СР-408", "ТМ-14-9", "ТМ-206", "ТМ-306", "ТМ-406", "ТО-14-8", "ТО-210", "ТО-310",
            "ТО-410", "УД-14-11", "УД-211", "УД-213К", "УК-14-10", "УК-207", "УК-307", "УК-311", "УК-407",
            "ЭЭ-14-23", "ЭЭ-313", "ЮС-14-14", "ЮС-14-15К", "ЮС-14-16К", "ЮС-209", "ЮС-212К", "ЮС-309"};
    protected Intent intent;
    private String groupName;
    private String nameGroup;
    private searchGroup sG;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.srchgroup);
        group = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        group.addTextChangedListener(this);
        group.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, spisokGrp));
        sG=new searchGroup();
        /**button.setOnClickListener(this);*/
    }
    class searchGroup extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        Elements nameGrp;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            groupName = group.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://pkgh.edu.ru/obuchenie/shedule-of-classes.html").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (doc != null) {
                nameGrp = doc.select("h4.expanded");
                nameGroup = nameGrp.html();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            intent.putExtra("nameGroup", nameGroup);
        }
    }
    public void click(View view) {
        int i;
        boolean bool;
        sG.execute();
        groupName = group.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        bool = false;

        do {
            for (i = 0; i < spisokGrp.length; i++) {
                if (groupName.equals(spisokGrp[i])) {
                    groupName = spisokGrp[i];
                    bool = true;
                    intent.putExtra("group", groupName);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Неверный ввод", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bool = true;
                }
            }
        } while (!bool);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите стартовать новую активити передав ей оба значения (из цикла обхода массива и результат работы **AsyncTask**), то запускать активити надо из метода **onPostExecute**() вашего класса **AsyncTask**.

В вашем же коде вы запускаете **AsyncTask** и не проверив завершил ли он работу (а он скорее всего (99.(9)%) не успел отработать) запускаете активити. Так в интент ничего из **AsyncTask**-а и не добавляется.

Вам надо переработать класс **AsyncTask** (почитав где, зачем и как его правильно пользовать) для вашей задачи. Во первых точно не надо полям класса активити присваивать значения в **doInBackground**. Это надо делать в **onPostExecute** (хотя и это не верный подход) в **UI** потоке, передав найденную строку в него из **doInBackground**. При этом должен будет измениться ваш **AsyncTask** класс примерно так:

```
class searchGroup extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        groupName = group.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://pkgh.edu.ru/obuchenie/shedule-of-classes.html").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (doc != null) {
            nameGrp = doc.select("h4.expanded");
            nameGroup = nameGrp.html();
            return nameGroup;
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        intent.putExtra("nameGroup", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: `protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        intent.putExtra("nameGroup", result); }` - а вот так добавляется в интент?
_Во первых точно не надо полям класса активити присваивать значения в doInBackground._ - это вы о **nameGroup**? Мне нужно создать локальную переменную? 
И если вам не трудно, не могли бы поделиться ссылкой(ами), как правильно использовать AsyncTask для таких действий? У меня есть 2 ссылки, ведующие на хабру, где я как раз и читаю о AsyncTask, но лишние не помешают, спасибо.

Comment: И еще, onPostExecute - это же поток UI?
doInBackground - не основной поток? Почему тогда не правильно? Правило: обращаться к компонентам только через UI поток.